# Incoming webhook message appears from 'Unknown User' in mobile app, correct webhook name in web interface

Tags: google-hangouts

I have an incoming webhook in a Google Chat room called 'Github Bot'. A Python script hits the webhook URL with a standard message POST payload.

The web interface at https://chat.google.com shows the correct name 'Github Bot' in any messages received to this webhook.

[image: Google Chat web interface view showing correct webhook name]

But the mobile Chat application shows those same messages as coming from 'Unknown User'.

[image: Google Chat mobile app view showing Unknown User]

Is there any way to make the mobile app use the webhook's name as the sender, same as the web interface does? E.G, is there some attribute I can send as part of the payload, or is this simply a bug/non-implementation on the mobile app and I can't do anything about it?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried reproducing this and I'm getting the same behavior in the mobile app as in the web interface (the bot name and the label `Bot` as displayed). Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm running Google Chat app on iOS 15.0. Note that it's not a bot but an incoming webhook, which seems to be a distinct thing according to the docs: https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/webhooks 

I can't provide an example right now but if it helps, the webhook is extremely similar to the Python example given in the docs (the http POST is identical) https://developers.google.com/chat/quickstart/incoming-bot-python . The webhook was made first (and given a name) in the Chat and then the webhook URL was used in the python script to send the message.

Comment: Yes, I had tested this with webhooks, as you mentioned it in your question. I had tested this in Android, but I just tested in iOS and I'm getting the same behavior as before (that is, the same behavior as in the web interface). Have you experienced this behavior in other mobile devices, as well as with other webhooks and spaces?

Comment: Yes, it's been reproduced on several iPhones, with different webhooks in different spaces. 

One other user has an Android phone and the bot name appears properly as desired.

One thing I probably should have mentioned is that this is a 'private' or business organisation G-suite e.g not public rooms. I have a theory that maybe it's trying to enumerate the user name from the users that belong to the org. But perhaps only on iOS devices..

Comment: I also tried with private rooms, and it's working for me in an Android phone as well as an iPhone. Probably will not be of any use, but can you provide the code you're using? Also, interestingly, I tried iOS 14.7.1 instead. Can you test it with that version, if you have the chance?

Comment: Thanks again for your continued help here. [Here is code](https://gist.github.com/mig5/5838311016ba00e27d93c0197bf7ff8a) that for me triggers 'Unknown user' as the name on Google Chat app v0.259.397432397 on iOS 15. All you'd need to do is change the webhook URL. 

I can't get my hands on an iOS 14.7.1 device at this time :( but I'll try to find someone who hasn't yet upgraded.. thanks

Comment: I just discovered that the bot name appears perfectly fine, even on iOS 15, if there is no avatar for the bot.

If I remove the avatar of an existing bot that was being seen as 'Unknown user', and make it send another message, the correct name appears.

Astonishing that the avatar makes a difference, but there you go!

Comment: ![screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/0flHuvn) - while there is an avatar, 'Unknown user'. With the avatar removed, bot name and BOT status seen correctly.

Comment: I tried a webhook with an avatar and it's still showing up correctly on Android. I don't have any iOS device at my disposal right now to test this. Have you checked whether it works in Android for you?

Comment: yes, sorry I didn't make that clear above ("One other user has an Android phone and the bot name appears properly as desired"). On Android: the bot name is correct regardless of avatar. On iOS: it's only correct if there is no avatar.

Comment: Hi, I have been able to reproduce this and I have reported it in Google Issue Tracker. I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69434779) explaining this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This seems to be a bug:

The webhook name and the `Bot` label are not shown properly on the iOS mobile app if an avatar is added to the webhook:

[image]

On Android, and on the web browser, the name and the `Bot` label are displayed correctly:

[image]

#### Reported in Issue Tracker:

I went ahead and reported this behavior in Google Issue Tracker:

- [Messages from incoming webhooks are not displayed properly on iOS](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/201946433)

I'd suggest you to [star this issue](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#subscribing_by_starring_an_issue) in order to keep track of this and to help prioritizing it.